# How to show CPU usage in a Chart c#

Tags: c#, charts, cpu-usage

so i have managed to display my CPU Usage in a textbox and a progress bar with this code

```
progressBar1.Value = (int)(performanceCounter1.NextValue());
label1.Text = "CPU Usage " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
```

Now can anyone help me move this onto a chart where the line moves across the page every time it refreshes.

p.s i have never used charts before.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this web page: [CPU Usage with graphical indication using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/442797/CPU-Usage-with-graphical-indication-using-Csharp-N)

i found this result with simply typing: show CPU usage Chart c#

Google is your greatest ally if you know how to talk to it...

It might help, But i am no expert on this, i only properly used google

Comment: Yes, i also found this example, but i cant find "using Org.Mentalis.Utilities;" in my references, the main bit

Comment: "This article describes how to measure CPU usage using C#. For this example I have used a set of defined based classes provided by http://www.mentalis.org. You can download the supporting class from http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=12. " that is the class that is called upon with the "using Org.Mentalis.Utilities;"

Comment: Let me know if that helped you out, I´m done for today will be online again tomorrow, Good luck

Comment: @Andrew, I forgot to use the @ Function

Comment: @Andrew do not forget to accept an answer or edit the post to tell us how it was solved, so that in the future the research for others is at a minimum

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of charts, so all you need is to plot CPU usage on an XY line chart.

There are plenty of charting toolkits (libraries) available online (some free some licensed). You can also find many articles describing how to start plotting in C#. I just googled, and found how you can start. [Check this!](http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/easy-way-to-plot-graphs-in-c-and-visual-studio-2010/)

PS: I will have a good advice for you. Make youself good user of GOOGLE!

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CpuUsageTest
{
public partial class frmCpuUsage : Form
{
public frmCpuUsage()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
progressBar1.Value = (int)(performanceCounter1.NextValue());
label1.Text = "Processor Time: " + 
progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
}
}
}
```

you may miss some Using..sorry my English is not well....I forget to paste all codes orz

Comment: You just re-wrote what i done for a progress bar -_- i need for a chart